# Objective-C, how do I convert a double to an int?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I must be doing something really obviously wrong, but I can't see it.

[image]

Comment: I think now is a good idea for you to learn C :D

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A double is a C type, not an Objective-C object. Hence you use C casts:

```
double myDouble = 3.2;
int myInt = (int)myDouble;
```

Comment: I believe NSDouble is the objective C counterpart, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Joe D: There's only NSInteger (which is a typedef to int *or* long depending on 32/64bit), but there's NSNumber, which wraps C data types into an object.

Comment: Try this, You will get a wrong value
```
double myDouble = 1609412671980.7009;
int myInt = (int)myDouble;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just converting mentioned above is good enough though you might want to use floor() or ceil() functions before that.

Comment: I found this to be important especially in the context of the question needing accuracy for payments. I found simple numbers like 230 converting to 229 after the integer conversion.

Comment: I believe it is bad practice to use floating point for prices representation. Correct way is to use integers (in cents, so $2 price is 200) and convert those to "2.00" just on output. Also Cocoa provides NSDecimalNumber class that is used by iOS itself for price representation.

Answer (score 1):

**intValue** is a method for a **NSNumber** instance.
For scale type like int, double, and float, they are not class type. So, they have no methods. Some languages like C# may wrap int, or double as a object, and they can be transfered to each other by a sub-routine.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSInteger number=33;
NSUInteger count = (NSInteger)[number];
```

here, **NSUInteger** is **long**. 
number **is NSInteger**

Comment: Will it convert a `double` value to `int`?

Comment: This code makes no sense

Answer (score -5):

```
double myDouble = 3.2;

int myInt = @(myDouble).intValue;
```

Sample of code I actually use:

```
NSNumber * percentLike1 = @(@(self.percentLike.doubleValue*100).integerValue);
```

Comment: -1: That's a very roundabout and inefficient way of converting. Essentially you're creating an object from a primitive just to grab another primitive value. If you had this in a loop, this would likely have a noticeable impact.

Comment: the complexity is constant. That's all I care. No it's not noticeable.

Comment: How is your code less complex, or even more readable, than `(int)myDouble`?

Comment: Also, I tested your code (the top block) compared to Georg's, both in the simulator. You want to know the difference? His was *72 times faster*. How is that not noticeable? Why would you use less readable, considerably slower code? You didn't even test your code before trying to disprove my accusations, did you? Please stop throwing silly notions around without evidence to back them up.