# How to convert NSTimeInterval to int?

Tags: iphone, ios, integer, nstimeinterval

How do I convert NSTimeInterval into an Integer value?

My TimeInterval holds the value `83.01837`. I need to convert it into `83`. I have googled but couldn't find any help.

Comment: NSTimeInterval is simply a double. You can cast it.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058198/objective-c-how-do-i-convert-a-double-to-an-int

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Direct assignment:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 1002343.5432542;
NSInteger time = interval;
//time is now equal to 1002343
```

NSTimeInterval is a double, so if you assign it directly to a NSInteger (or int, if you wish) it'll work.  This will cut off the time to the nearest second.

If you wish to round to the nearest second (rather than have it cut off) you can use round before you make the assignment:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 1002343.5432542;
NSInteger time = round(interval);
//time is now equal to 1002344
```

Comment: Possibly want a `round()` call in there.

Comment: hmmm...wouldn't it be better to just add .5 to interval?  I know I'm really bickering here but the effect will be the same without using up a function call.

Comment: Actually, round is better, seeing as it works properly with negative numbers as expected, whilst adding .5 or to the number doesn't...

Comment: Ahh true enough...pesky negatives. :)

Answer (score 8):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW69), `NSTimeInterval` is just a `double`:

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

You can cast this to an `int`:

```
seconds = (int) myTimeInterval;
```

Watch out for overflows, though!

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 3.0

```
let timestamp = round(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

[image]

Comment: This will give you with the decimal point followed by 0. (83.01837--> 83.0)

Comment: Kindly check the attached screenshot @prakash

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that NSTimeInterval values from NSDate would overflow an NSInteger. You'd likely want a long long. (64 bit integer.) Those can store honking-big integer values (-2^63 to 2^63 -1)

```
long long integerSeconds = round([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

### EDIT:

It looks like an NSInteger **CAN** store an NSTimeInterval, at least for the next couple of decades. The current date's timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate is about 519,600,000, or about 2^28. On a 32 bit device, and NSInteger can hold a value from -2^31 to 2^31-1. (2^31 is 2,147,483,648

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4, Swift 5**

I simply cast to `Int64`:

```
Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a need to store an NSDate in a Swift Number.  I used the following cast which is working great.

```
Double(startDateTime.timeIntervalSince1970)
```

Comment: Double() doesn't create integeg value