# Convert NSTimInterval to Integer Swift

Tags: swift, nstimeinterval

I need to convert a variable of type NSTimeInterval, which I know is a Double, to an Integer. I have already tried the solutions here: [How to convert NSTimeInterval to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121459/how-to-convert-nstimeinterval-to-int) , with no success. Can anyone give any suggestions on how to do this in Swift?
Below is my function:

```
func getHKQuantityData(sampleType: HKSampleType, timeUnit: NSCalendarUnit, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate, completion: (Void -> Void)) -> [(NSDate, Double)] {
    var startTime = 0
    var endTime = 0
    var repeat: NSTimeInterval
    var returnValue: [(NSDate, Double)] = []
    var queryType: String = ""
    var predicate: NSPredicate!
    let timeInterval = endDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)
    switch sampleType {
    case HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount):
        queryType = "step"
    case HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight):
        queryType = "height"
    case HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass):
        queryType = "weight"
    case HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex):
        queryType = "bmi"
    default:
        println("No recognized type")
    }

    switch timeInterval {
    // 1. Case for seconds
    case 0...59:
        predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitSecond, value: startTime, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), endDate: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitSecond, value: startTime, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), options: .None)
        repeat = timeInterval
    // 2. Case for minutes
    case 61...3599:
        predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitMinute, value: startTime, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), endDate: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitMinute, value: startTime, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), options: .None)
        repeat = round(timeInterval / 60)
    // 3. Case for Hours
    case 3600...86399:
        predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitHour, value: startTime, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), endDate: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitHour, value: startTime, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), options: .None)
        repeat = round(timeInterval / 3600)
    // 4. Default for Days
    default:
        predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: startTime, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), endDate: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: startTime, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), options: .None)
        repeat = round(timeInterval / 86400)
    }
    /*
    for x in 1...repeat {

    }
    */


    // Returns one data point for each timeUnit between startDate and endDate
    // array of tuples - (date, double)

    return returnValue
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Coerce:

```
let i = Int(myTimeInterval)
```

**EDIT** In a comment, it is rightly pointed out that this approach can fail (and crash), because the Double contained in `myTimeInterval` might be larger than the maximum size of an Int, causing overflow.

Until Swift 4, dealing with that possibility was quite difficult. But Swift 4 introduces two new Int initializers that solve the problem:

- `init(exactly:)` — this is a failable initializer, so it returns an Optional Int which might be `nil`.
- `init(clamping:)` — this always succeeds, because if it would fail due to overflow, the largest legal Int is substituted.

Comment: On this way you can get 
`fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max`

Comment: @malex That problem is solved in Swift 4 with the `exactly:` and `clamping:` initializers.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast a Double value to Int like this: `Int(exampleValue)`

Comment: then publish your code in your question, so that we can see what exactly is going on.